# Where to host wagtail/django

Tags: django, ssh, web-hosting, wagtail

Hi I have a bit of experience in WordPress but none in PHP however, I do in python. As you can imagine editing plugins to suit my needs is a bit hit and miss. I recently discovered wagtail and saw it ran on django, for me this would be far better. I researched how to host django remotely and got thousands of tutorials on python 2.7. The website says

```
# in a Python 3 virtual environment
pip install wagtail
wagtail start mysite
cd mysite
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py runserver
```

Do you just ssh in and do this as you would on a local machine, if so which host should I use and how do you even ssh a web server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail is a Django based framework. To be able to host a wagtail website, you need to know how to deploy a Django website.

Deploying a django application: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to deploy it on [heroku](https://heroku.com). Just open up a free account and deploy it. There are few steps to perform to make the code run without issues. Their [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-django) clearly gives you an idea of what to do.

If you do have a server instance, then the way I do it is to set up `gunicorn` for your project and then create a proxy server using `nginx`. Then configure `supervisor` to make sure your app is running at all times. [Here](https://dev.to/ppshobi/an-in-depth-tutorial-on-deploying-a-django-application-into-aws-58m5) is good video tutorial on how to do it. Cheers.

Comment: What about the idle though and the only way to remove that is to pay 7£ a month

Comment: If you are actually running a production app, you will be buying some server space or be getting an ec2 instance or something along those lines. This will a tad bit expensive, but will remove the major headaches of setting up the server and all. You are paying for the ease of use, to put it into perspective.